# Select menu element with Selenium

Tags: java, html, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I would like to select an element of a dropdown menu using Selenium in a Java application.
I tried several times using Select, List < WebElement > etc... with no success.
The html of the webpage is this:

```html
<div class="margin-top_2">          
  <span class="right_column_2">
          <div id="f1:idSelectTipoDoc" class="ui-selectonemenu ui-widget ui-state-default ui-corner-all ui-helper-clearfix" style="vertical-align: middle; width: 198px;">
          <div class="ui-helper-hidden-accessible">
          <select id="f1:idSelectTipoDoc_input" name="f1:idSelectTipoDoc_input" style="vertical-align:middle">
          <option value="">Select a fruit</option><option value="A">Apple</option>
          <option value="T">Tangerine</option></select>
          </div>
          <input type="text" name="f1:idSelectTipoDoc_editableInput" class="ui-selectonemenu-label ui-inputfield ui-corner-all" tabindex="-1" style="cursor: pointer; width: 182px;">
          <div class="ui-selectonemenu-trigger ui-state-default ui-corner-right"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-triangle-1-s"></span></div></div></span>
</div>
```

This was my last try but the element in dropdown menu was not selected:

```js
//open the dropdown menu
WebElement tipo1 = new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"f1:idSelectTipoDoc\"]/div[2]")));
tipo1.click();
// select the Apple line
WebElement tipo2 = new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"f1:idSelectTipoDoc\"]")));
Select elem = new Select(tipo2);
elem.selectByVisibleText("Apple");
```

Anyone know why it is not working? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

your locator is wrong, you are using locator for div element and not select. use:

```
WebElement tipo2 = new WebDriverWait(driver, Duration.ofSeconds(5)).until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//select[@id=\"f1:idSelectTipoDoc_input\"]")));
Select elem = new Select(tipo2);
elem.selectByVisibleText("Apple");
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. Unfortunately with this code I got the : "Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" org.openqa.selenium.StaleElementReferenceException: A node reference could not be resolved:......" error